# an Emacs cursor movement hook, like the JavaScript mousemove event

Tags: emacs

I want to track the "current word" in the current buffer. which another (networked) application will be aware of.

I could do this by sending a request every time the cursor moves, whether from clicking or scrolling or arrowing or etc. i.e. any time the cursor's position in the buffer changes.

e.g.

```
(add-hook 'cursor-move-hook 'post-request-with-current-word)
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Properties.html) would have me believe that you can do with with the `point-entered` or `point-left` props, but this does not appear to be the case. See [this bug report](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gnu.emacs.bug/N3EQOLt2mOE/AYaeqcBFyEsJ) for details. You should be able to get this to work by ensuring that each potential "current word" in your buffer has a different text property so the `point-entered` hook will be triggered, but I'm not sure how practical (performance wise) this would be...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `post-command-hook` this will run after every command, including movement commands.

Obviously this will fire more often than you want, so in your hook, you could do something like keep track of the last position you were at when the hook was run and only fire the network request if the current point differs from the last like so:

```lisp
(defvar last-post-command-position 0
  "Holds the cursor position from the last run of post-command-hooks.")

(make-variable-buffer-local 'last-post-command-position)

(defun do-stuff-if-moved-post-command ()
  (unless (equal (point) last-post-command-position)
    (let ((my-current-word (thing-at-point 'word)))
      ;; replace (message ...) with your code
      (message "%s" my-current-word)))
  (setq last-post-command-position (point)))

(add-to-list 'post-command-hook #'do-stuff-if-moved-post-command)
```

Comment: that's the good idea. I think I'd want my state to be both line position and buffer name.

Comment: buffer-name is taken care of since last-post-command-position is buffer local so the comparison is always buffer specific. There is a different value of last-post-command-position per buffer.

Comment: reading https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Command-Overview.html#Command-Overview, and adding a logger to the hook, it seems that a command is one of: keyboard/mouse event, interactive function, Emacs server request. is that complete?